# Suppress watchdog a specific log message

Tags: log-messages

I would like to tell watchdog **not** to write the "Cron run completed" to the log while leaving all other messages intact. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is no special hook for this. The easiest way to fix this in Drupal 8 is overriding *logger.dblog* service.

According to the [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) you need implement a class extending *ServiceProviderBase* and the *alter*() method as shown below.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Modifies the logger.dblog service.
 */
class ExampleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // Overrides logger.dblog service to exclude some unwanted log messages.
    $container->getDefinition('logger.dblog')
      ->setClass('Drupal\example\Logger\DbLog');
  }

}
```

The logger itself is extremely simple.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Logger;

use Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog as BaseDbLog;

/**
 * Logs events in the watchdog database table.
 */
class DbLog extends BaseDbLog {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function log($level, $message, array $context = []) {
    if ($message !== 'Cron run completed.') {
      parent::log($level, $message, $context);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Drupal 7 for the project where I want to suppress the messages... Any way to do that there?

Answer (score 2):

For drupal 7 you could implement `hook_watchdog()` in a custom module to see the error messages but it will not allow you to change the messages logged into database.  Read more about `hook_watchdog` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7.x)

For deleting specific messages perhaps you could implement `hook_cron` in your own module using something similar to what watchdog does when cleaning itself from excess messages as seen [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21dblog%21dblog.module/function/dblog_cron/7.x) but you have to adjust the code to find only specific messages to delete.

Perhaps viewing all log message except the ones you mentioned can be done with https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog which allows you to create a view of dblog message and probably you can use views filtering to filter them out.

Or https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdog_filtering might be able to do the filtering for you

Comment: Thank you very much GiorgosK! So many ideas - I will check them all and comment here again. Amir

Comment: Hi, I have chosen the Views Watchdog module - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to **not** write a specific log message, you can also ue the [Views Watchdog](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog) module (to not include such messages when creating a list of log messages).

Some details about this module (from its project page):

> ... extends the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and allows to create customized lists (pages, blocks, feeds) of watchdog entries.
>
> **Features**
>
> This module provides several fields, filter and sort criteria to build custom pages, blocks, and feeds.
>
> It also provides the style Watchdog table to display watchdog entries as highlighted rows in a table.