# Message shown in popup whenever any error log is registered

Tags: 8, log-messages

I want the administrator users to see a popup whenever an error log is generated. I researched and already completed the first step following [Additional actions when logging using watchdog](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266089/additional-actions-when-logging-using-watchdog).

BetterMonitoring is my custom module. This the code I am using.

#### BetterMonitoring.service.yml

```yaml
services:

  logger.BetterMonitoring:
    class: Drupal\BetterMonitoring\Logger\BetterMonitoring
    tags:
      - { name: logger_custom }
```

#### BetterMonitoring.php

```php
namespace Drupal\BetterMonitoring\Logger;

use Drupal\Core\Logger\RfcLoggerTrait;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BetterMonitoring implements LoggerInterface {
  use RfcLoggerTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) {
    // I want to check  whether the message is an error; if it is, show it in a popup.
  }

}
```

How do I check whether the message is an error message inside this log function and then show it in the popup?

Comment: @kiamlaluno -  Inside the "function log($level.........)" how can we check whether the log is of type ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation for [`LoggerInterface::log()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21psr%21log%21Psr%21Log%21LoggerInterface.php/function/LoggerInterface%3A%3Alog/8.9.x) doesn't make clear what value the `$level` parameter gets, the code used from [`RfcLoggerTrait::error()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Logger%21RfcLoggerTrait.php/function/RfcLoggerTrait%3A%3Aerror/8.9.x) makes that clearer.

```php
public function error($message, array $context = []) {
  $this->log(RfcLogLevel::ERROR, $message, $context);
}
```

`RfcLogLevel::ERROR` is the value passed for error messages.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Logger\RfcLogLevel;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\RfcLoggerTrait;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BetterMonitoring implements LoggerInterface {
  use RfcLoggerTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) {
    if ($level == RfcLogLevel::ERROR) {
      $this->storeMessage($message, $context);
    }
  }

}
```

As for showing the message in a popup, since the logger cannot render markup in a page, I would do as the [`Messenger`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21Messenger.php/class/Messenger/8.9.x) class does: Instantiate an object implementing [`FlashBagInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Session%21Flash%21FlashBagInterface.php/interface/FlashBagInterface/8.9.x) and store the messages in that object. For a logger, which is a service, it's enough to add *@session.flash_bag* between its arguments.

```yaml
services:

  logger.BetterMonitoring:
    class: Drupal\BetterMonitoring\Logger\BetterMonitoring
    arguments:
      - '@session.flash_bag'
    tags:
      - { name: logger_custom }
```

In this case, the logger also needs a class constructor.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

public function __construct(FlashBagInterface $flash_bag) {
  $this->flashBag = $flash_bag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @kiamlaluno Now I am successfully able to check "Error" type of logs. **But please explain how can i push those "ERROR" type messages into flashbag popup.**. Popup is not working. I am not sure whether i am calling it the right way. Please help! I have placed constructor as suggested by you.
**Here is the logger Code**
`code`
            public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) {
                if ($level == RfcLogLevel::ERROR) {
                $flash_bag =\Drupal::logger('custom_logger')->warning("inside-error-logger");
                }
            }

Comment: `\Drupal::logger('custom_logger')->warning("inside-error-logger")` doesn't return any value and it doesn't return an object implementing `FlashBagInterface`. With the constructor I show in the answer, the flash bag is already available in `$this->flashBag`. The logger stores the message somewhere (for example in a flash bag) and the popup retrieves the messages from there. Unfortunately, adding the code for the popup would make the answer too broad, given the question doesn't contain any details about that.

Comment: Also, the answer is simply suggesting a way to store those messages. The important part is that the logger cannot be used to render a message, but store messages in some places. That is what the [`DbLog`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21src%21Logger%21DbLog.php/class/DbLog/8.9.x) class does, and what the [`SysLog`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21syslog%21src%21Logger%21SysLog.php/class/SysLog/8.9.x) class does too, which uses  [`syslog()`](http://php.net/syslog) to store the message in the system log.