# How do I tell logging to ignore messages that I have seen?

Tags: log-messages

I've got a couple of log messages that are coming out every few minutes. I can't fix them as they are just part of the system. How do I tell watchdog to ignore them?

Comment: Is it Drupal 7 or 8? And also whats the "Type", "Severity" and "Message".

Comment: D7. Say warning but it happens across the severity list. e.g. deprecated php methods cause a warning. 'Hide messages like these' is what I'd want.

Comment: Check out this link. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220173/suppress-watchdog-a-specific-log-message#answer-235197